# Find the area of triangle $SVW$

Tags: trigonometry, area

[image]

To find length of side $SV$ I used Pythagoras theorem which gave $SV=17$.
To find angle $SVW$ I added $45$ to $90 = 135$
to find side length $SW = 17^2+24^2-2 \cdot 17 \cdot 24 \cdot \cos135=37$
and lastly, to find area of the triangle I used Heron's formula $\sqrt{39(39-17)(39-24)(39-37)} = 160$ but the correct answer is $56.25$

Comment: The area of SVW=0.5 * area of RSVW.

Comment: $VW$ is perpendicular to the plane holding $TSQV$. So the angle between $VW$ and any line in the plane through $V$ is $90^\circ$. In particular, $\angle SVW = 90^\circ$.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

$SV$ is perpendicular to $WV$ and $SV=\sqrt{VT^2+ST^2}$.

The area of the triangle is given by $\frac12 \cdot SV \cdot WV$.

Comment: 0.5*17*24=204 ? still not 56.25

Comment: The answer is probably incorrect then.

Answer (score 1):

It's $$\frac{24\cdot\sqrt{15^2+8^2}}{2}.$$